# How to get latency details of load balancer in stackdriver?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, latency, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have a simple spring boot application deployed on Kubernetes on GCP. I wish to custom auto-scale the application using latency threshold (response time). Stackdriver has a set of metrics for load balancer. Details of the metrics can be found in [this link](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-loadbalancing).

I have exposed my application to an external IP using the following command

`kubectl expose deployment springboot-app-new --type=LoadBalancer --port 80 --target-port 9000`

I used this [API explorer](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.timeSeries/list?apix_params=%7B%22name%22%3A%22projects%2Fapim-testing%22%2C%22filter%22%3A%22metric.type%20%3D%20%5C%22loadbalancing.googleapis.com%2Fhttps%2Fbackend_latencies%5C%22%22%2C%22interval.endTime%22%3A%222019-10-16T12%3A46%3A00Z%22%2C%22interval.startTime%22%3A%222019-10-16T11%3A31%3A00Z%22%7D) to view the metrics. The response code is 200, but the response is empty.
The metrics filter I used is `metric.type = "loadbalancing.googleapis.com/https/backend_latencies"`

**Question**

1. Why am I not getting anything in the response? Am I making any mistake?
2. I have already enabled Stackdriver API. Is there any other settings to be made to get the response?

Comment: That metric is for HTTP(S) Load Balancers. A service type LoadBlancer creates a Network Load Balancer.

Comment: This link will help you with available metrics for Network Load Balancers: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/tcp/tcp-ssl-proxy-logging-monitoring

Comment: If you want to use HTTP(S) Load Balancers: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/container-native-load-balancing

Comment: In the link you suggested for Network load balancer, it instructs to go to **Monitoring-->Resources --> Google Cloud Load Balancers** but in the **Monitoring--> Resources**, **Google Cloud Load Balancer** option is not available. Do you have any suggestions for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58443873/how-to-get-latency-details-of-load-balancer-in-stackdriver#comment103244631_58443873), the metric you're trying to use belongs to an HTTP(S) load balancer and the type `LoadBalancer`, when used in GKE, will deploy a [Network Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/network/) instead.

The reason you're not able to find its metrics using the Stackdriver Monitoring page is that, the link shared in the comment corresponds to a [TCP/SSL Proxy load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl/) (layer 7) documentation instead of a [Network Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/network/) (layer 4), which is the one that is already created in your cluster and for now, the Network Load Balancer won't show up using the Stackdriver Monitoring page.

However, a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/70662343) has been created to have this functionality enabled in the Monitoring dashboard.

If you need to have this particular metric (`loadbalancing.googleapis.com/https/backend_latencies`), it might be best to [expose your deployment using an Ingress](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer) instead of using the `LoadBalancer` type. This will automatically create an HTTP(S) load balancer with the monitoring enabled instead of the current Network Load Balancer.

Comment: This was really useful. As the collected data in Stackdriver is not available instantly, I also like to know whether it is possible to configure a LoadBalancer to get the latency details?